# Replicating jQuery' slideDown() with Vue

Tags: jquery, vue.js, animation, transition

I'm trying to apply [this example](https://codepen.io/kdydesign/pen/VrQZqx) to make my content appear, upon clicking a button, with a vertical slide animation similar to jQuery' slideUp/slideDown.

My content is inside some `Portfolio` component that I call thus:

```
<portfolio v-if="portfolioOpen" />
```

Clicking a button toggles variable `portfolioOpen` from `false` to `true`, then in my Portfolio component I have this:

```
<style lang="scss">
  .portfolio-enter-active,
  .portfolio-leave-active {
     transition: all 100ms ease-in 0s
  }

  .portfolio-enter-to,
  .portfolio-leave {
     max-height: 1000px;
     overflow: hidden;
  }

  .portfolio-enter,
  .portfolio-leave-to {
     overflow: hidden;
     max-height: 0;
  }
</style>
```

I can't find any difference between this and the pen mentioned above. It works well in the pen, but in my case the animation only works when hiding my content. When my content is shown the animation doesn't work, it's shown instantly.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't work with `v-if` because then the content isn't there on page load and it takes time for Vue to summon it which prevents the CSS animation to work properly.

Instead, `v-show` must be used so that the content is already there in the DOM.